# Best way to store character info

Tags: libgdx

I am creating a simple 2D game. I have player character and enemies that spawn each level. Every level has its own set of enemies with count of 1-6. Player character can level up into various classes - meaning that every class has its own textures. 
**What is the best way to store data about player character (player textures, attributes) 
How to tell the game how to position enemies (different layout on different number of enemies)**

I read about JSON, but apparently it is to slow, if you have big amount of data (I am not sure if my case is slow in that way). In my case there is about 30 different player paths and many many more different cases of enemy positions.

Comment: What do you mean by "player paths"? You shouldn't have some array with thousands of X,Y pairs describing every single move of some character.  Instead you should store some key positions and interpolate movement between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store textures, sounds, tiled maps, fonts, etc. Use [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) class. It loads textures and other resources excellent in real time (Without loosing FPS). Also you can `unload` resources if they aren't need anymore. And `load` them again when there is a need.

JSON isn't that slow how you describe. Store only data that is unique for every entity. For example zombie enemies:

```
{
"zombie" {"x": 100, "y": 10},
"zombie" {"x": 100, "y": 20},
}
```

Other data can be declared in class.

```
class Zombie {

   int width;
   int height;
   Texture texture;

   int x; // initialize later, when load from JSON
   int y;

   public Zombie(Texture texture, int width, int, height){
       this.texture = texture;
       this.width = width;
       this.height = height;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Preferences class. It's very easy and convenient. To save the current texture of the player, you do not need to store the texture itself. You can save the texture index, or its name:

```
Preferences progress;
...
progress.putInteger("playerTextureIndex ", 0); // for save
playerTextureIndex = progress.getInteger("playerTextureIndex ", 0); // for load
```

Then initiate the appropriate texture.

Answer (score 0):

For the positioning of enemies I like to define the positions in the Tiled Maps (.tmx). Inside the editor I just create a simple rectangle to mark the position.

In the code then I get all the `MapObjects` and assign those to Box2D bodies and fixtures. I usually edit the width and height because it's not very common to have a sprite's size that works out perfectly in tiles.

Then inside the constructor for the `Sprite` class I take in a Box2D body.

For assets the best way to load and store them is with the `AssetManager`. It loads all assets in very fast time and is a much better solution than just loading them without it.

I hope this answer helped you and if you have any further questions please post a comment below!

Comment: Thank you, so far as I see, that editor might solve my problem :)

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, I personally think that this solution is the cleanest and my preferred method for this problem. Tiled maps are also the most popular format for 2D tilemaps and are supported in nearly all game engines.